# (New in Sencha 2.2) Data store loading data for large data set freezes app

Tags: sencha-touch-2

There is a data store in my app that, on a specific user action, gets loaded with a rather large set of data via a local txt file (100kb total). Prior to my upgrade to Sencha 2.2, loading that data set went rather quickly and there was 0 impact on the app performance.

Now that I've upgraded to Sencha 2.2, loading that data freezes the app completely. Even if I'm running the app on my computer, it takes around 5 minutes for the app to unfreeze.

I've tried two approaches: setData() and loading via a proxy (code below). Both approaches have the same result. I've sifted through the Sencha 2.2 changelog and haven't been able to find any relevant changes to data stores. I'm pretty well at a loss here. Any help would be awesome.

Local proxy approach:

```
Ext.define("addable_exercises", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Model",
    config: {
    idProperty: 'id',
    fields: [
        { name: 'ex_id'},
        { name: 'ex_name'},
        { name: 'ex_alias'},
        { name: 'ex_type'},
        { name: 'prot_type'}
    ]
}
});


var all_exercises = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId:    'all_exercises',
    model:    'addable_exercises',
    proxy:    {
        type:    'ajax',
        url:    'resources/textfiles/datastores/all_exercises.txt'
    }
});

Ext.getStore('all_exercises').load()
```

setData() approach:

```
Ext.define("addable_exercises", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Model",
    config: {
    idProperty: 'id',
    fields: [
        { name: 'ex_id' },
        { name: 'ex_name'},
        { name: 'ex_alias'},
        { name: 'ex_type'},
        { name: 'prot_type'}
    ]
}
});


var all_exercises = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId:    'all_exercises',
    model:      'addable_exercises'
});

Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'resources/textfiles/datastores/all_exercises.txt',
    success: function(response, opts) {
        var exercise_list = response.responseText;
        var all_exercises_store = Ext.getStore('all_exercises');
        all_exercises_store.setData(exercise_list);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem wasn't the actual data store, it was what my code does immediately after loading that store: associating that massive store with a dataview list. In Sencha 2.2, lists are no longer set as `infinite` by default (which I assume was a performance consideration for short lists), so - as a non-infinite list - it was parsing every list item before displaying anything. With infinite enabled, it lets the items load in the background.

```
var list = new Ext.dataview.List({
            id:     'search_list',
            height: 500,
            width: 500,
            infinite: true,
            loadingText:'loading...',
            store:  'all_exercises',
            itemTpl: [
                '<tpl for=".">',
                '<div class="feed_item">',
                '<div class="avatar">{ex_name}</div>',
                '</div>',
                '</div>',
                '</tpl>'
            ]
        });
```